# Why does $.ajax({url:"xxx"}).responseText return undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does `$.ajax({url:"xxx"}).responseText` return `undefined`?
But if I use `a=$.ajax({url:"xxx"}), a.responseText` returns right result.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using `a.responseText` immediately after the assignment?

Comment: I had to test this, and it always returns `undefined` for me, as ajax is **Asynchronous**, and the responseText is returned when the call completes.

Comment: Thank you very much!I have got it!The reason is the default async is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a race condition (sort of).

Since AJAX is asynchronous, it runs in the background. When you do:

```
$.ajax({url:"xxx"}).responseText
```

you're fetching the `responseText` too fast. When you pass it to a value, the ajax manages to complete the call and `responseText` has a value.

You can really see it happen if you install something like [AJAX debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ajax-debugger/lgfefckpdealogpcfjdhinecfbcgedam?hl=en), which logs AJAX requests into your console. Then you'll see that you're getting the `undefined` response *before* completing the ajax call. You can also set `async: false` and see that a synchronous call would work (but don't do that, it kinda defies the point of AJAX).

note that even the second example can (sometimes) return an undefined value - bigger sites will take longer to return a response, so you can't really rely on it. The **right way** to do it would be to run the required logic inside the ajax [complete event](http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/) (or even better - the `success` event)

Comment: Also try setting `async` to `false` for the AJAX call and you should see it work.

Comment: @Jimbo you're right, though I wouldn't recommend doing that. It kinda defies the point. Instead, it's better to run the required logic inside the [`complete` event](http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/) of the ajax call (or, even better, the `success` event)

Comment: No no, I mean setting the `async` value to `false` would **prove** your point, and then could be switched back.

Comment: @Jimbo In that case you're right. I've incorporated it into the answer

Answer (score 0):

Your call is async. You need to use a function assigned to success to use the response. Please, read the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to clarify things.